# This location could not be displayed You do not the permissions necessary to view the contents of www

Tags: permissions, apache2, users

I cant acces `/var/www` all of the sudden... also I would like to just give the user "loko" all the permissions. How can i get the error I am getting all of the sudden and how to fix it? Yesterday it worked fine.

Comment: What command yielded this error? Also, have you got `sudo` permissions on the machine you are working with? I think output of `ls -la /var/www` might help too.

Comment: @moon.musick I just tried to open the directory

Comment: Open how? Using `nautilus` (i.e. the graphical file manager)? Using `ls /var/www`? Using Midnight Commander? There are many ways to access a directory.

Comment: @moon.musick Not sure really cause I started with Ubuntu yesterday but it's not with the command line. Probably Nautilus

Comment: Ok, if you have `sudo` access (you might check by opening a terminal and running `sudo ls .` or any other simple command - use your password for confirmation), you should be able to start privileged `nautilus` session with `gksu nautilus`. Then you'll have the access to restricted directories. Also, if you want to work with websites and such, I suggest you learn terminal commands, perhaps at http://linuxcommand.org

Comment: @moon.musick I cant change the permission of my /var/www :S I can with my other directorys/files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

These are the commands to give a directory or a file the permissions:

```
chmod 400 mydoc.txt read by owner
chmod 040 mydoc.txt read by group
chmod 004 mydoc.txt read by anybody (other)
chmod 200 mydoc.txt write by owner
chmod 020 mydoc.txt write by group
chmod 002 mydoc.txt write by anybody
chmod 100 mydoc.txt execute by owner
chmod 010 mydoc.txt execute by group
chmod 001 mydoc.txt execute by anybody
```

and I used this to give myself all the permissions:

```
sudo chown -R loko:sudo /home
```

Comment: You can combine these commands to something like `chmod 444 mydoc.txt`.